# laravel inertia vue: toast on create page only works once

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

My goal is to display a form on a page, and every time the form is submitted, we stay on the same page, and a toast notification appears.

So far, I've read the shared data documentation on inertia (flash message section), that works fine but I suppose the example assumes that after a form submit we redirect to the index page (i.e. the list of all categories), so not exactly what I want.

So far, here is my code.

CategoryController.php (no problem here)

```
public function store(CategoryRequest $request)
{
    $fields = $request->validated();

    Category::create([
        ...$fields,
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('categoryCreate')->with('message', "Category created successfully");
}
```

HandleInertiaRequests.php (no problem here)

```
public function share(Request $request): array
{
    return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
        'flash' => [
            'message' => session('message'),
        ],
    ]);
}
```

I spare you the vue form, which is quite regular, but basically it does this at the end (no problem here):

```
<script setup>
import {Head, useForm} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import AdminLayout from '@/Layouts/AdminLayout.vue';
import {computed, ref} from 'vue';

let props = defineProps({
  id: String | null,
  name: String,
  front_position: Number,
});

let form = useForm({
  ...props,
});


let submit = () => {
  form.post(route('categoryCreate'), {
    preserveScroll: true,
  });
};


</script>
```

In the layout of that vue form (**<- PROBLEM HERE ->**), I put my code, which works but is ugly :

layout, html part (in the template tag)

```
  <div v-if="isToastActive"
       class="text-white text-2xl bg-emerald-800 z-20 p-4 max-w-sm fixed right-2 top-2 mynotif active">
  {{ $page.props.flash.message }}
  </div>

  <div v-if="triggerToast"></div>
```

layout, script part:

```
<script setup>
import {Head} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import AdminNavbar from '@/components/Navbars/AdminNavbar.vue';
import Sidebar from '@/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.vue';
import HeaderStats from '@/components/Headers/HeaderStats.vue';
import FooterAdmin from '@/components/Footers/FooterAdmin.vue';
import {usePage} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import {computed, ref, watch} from 'vue';

const isToastActive = ref(false);

const triggerToast = computed(() => {
  let ret = usePage().props.value.flash.message;
  if (undefined !== ret) {

    isToastActive.value = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
      isToastActive.value = false;
    }, 3000);
  }
});





</script>
```

So, what I find ugly is that I have to create an extra element: `<div v-if="triggerToast"></div>` , which only serves the purpose of retriggering the computed method, in which I define the logic for retriggering the toast.

Note: if I don't do that, and just keep an html part like this (excerpt from the inertia doc):

```
      <div v-if="$page.props.flash.message" class="alert">
        {{ $page.props.flash.message }}
      </div>
```

Then the toast will **ONLY APPEAR ON THE FIRST SUBMIT,** and **WILL NOT APPEAR ON ANY SUBSEQUENT FORM SUBMIT** (and that's the problem)

So, is there a way to make the layout part more elegant, while keeping the constraint of staying on the same page?

Note: using logs, I know that the store method of the controller is executed every time I submit the form, so the server part is not the problem.